# How to convert a tuple of String to String*?

Tags: scala

Let's say, I have this function.

```
def foo(bar: String*): String = { bar.mkString(", ") }
```

which can take one or more string values as arguments.

```
scala> foo("hello", "world", "foo")
res4: String = hello, world, foo
```

But how do I make it such that the following also works.

```
scala> foo(("hello", "world", "foo"))
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String, String)
 required: String
              foo(("hello", "world", "foo"))
              ^
```

The number of strings which can be passed as an argument can be arbitrary. Why I need this is because, I have another method.

```
def fooHelper() = {
  ("hello", "world", "foo")  // Again, can be arbitrary number
}
```

which I want to use like this.

```
foo(fooHelper())
```

Comment: I don't think there is generic way of calling vararg function from tuples of unknown arity. It can be done using list value and `: _*`. Otherwise you can have a look at shapeless which allows more genericity.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution without using external library is to use `productIterator` which converts tuple to an iterator.

Use like

`foo(("a", "b").productIterator.toList.map(_.toString):_*)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples) library:

```
> import shapeless._
> import syntax.std.tuple._

> def foo(any: Any *) = { any.foreach(println) }
defined function foo

> foo((23, "foo", true).toList:_*)
23
foo
true
```

Also, as scala supports tuples only up to 22 elements, you can write (generate) unwrapping helper yourself.